# MVC Bootstrap form-control DropDownListFor validation error message not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am using MVC5 and I can not get the MVC validation message for DropDownList (with Bootsrap3). I researched similar problems on stackoverflow but any solutions work for me.

I want to user select option from drop down list. If he click "Submit" button and no option was selected he should get validation error message. Initially when page is loaded first time, any option is selected (selected is option with value "null").

**Model:**

```
public class CarsPriceSearchViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę wybrać markę"), Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]
    [Display(Name = "Marka")]
    public int SelectedBrandId { get; set; }
    public SelectList Brands { get; set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proszę wybrać model"), Range(1, Int32.MaxValue)]
    [Display(Name = "Model")]
    public int SelectedModelId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    oSelectList  = new List<SelectListItem>() {
                new SelectListItem(){ Value="1", Text="Audi"},
                new SelectListItem(){ Value="2", Text="BMW"}
    };
    oSearchViewModel.Brands = new SelectList(oSelectList, "Value", "Text");
    return View(oSearchViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Search(CarsPriceSearchViewModel searchOptions)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //TO sth
    }

    return View(searchOptions);
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SearchCarsOffersForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedBrandId)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedBrandId,
                        Model.Brands,
                        "--Wybierz-Markę--",
                        new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedBrandId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedModelId)
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedModelId,
                         new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "ModelId", "ModelName"),
                         "--Wybierz-Model--",
                         new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedModelId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button type="submit" id="SearchCarsOffers" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
                Szukaj
            </button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Remark**

In _Layout.cshtml I have included scripts:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

**Scripts**

```
$("#SelectedBrandId").change(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "UsedCarsPriceChart/FillBrandModels/",
            data: { id: $(this).val() /* add other additional parameters */ },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",

            success: function (models) {
                $("#SelectedModelId").html(""); // clear before appending new list

                $("#SelectedModelId").append(
                    $('<option></option>').html("--Wybierz-Model--"));
                for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
                    var model = models[i];
                    $("#SelectedModelId").append(                        
                        $('<option></option>').val(model.ModelId).html(model.ModelName));
                }
                //The same statement as above
                //$.each(models, function (i, model) {
                //    $("#SelectedModelId").append(
                //        $('<option></option>').val(model.ModelId).html(model.ModelName));
                //});

                $("#VersionModelId").html(""); // clear before appending new list
                $("#VersionModelId").append(
                    $('<option></option>').html("--Wybierz-Wersję--"));
            }
        });
    });

    $("#SelectedModelId").change(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "UsedCarsPriceChart/FillVersionModel/",
            data: { id: $(this).val() },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",

            success: function (models) {
                $("#VersionModelId").html(""); // clear before appending new list

                $("#VersionModelId").append(
                    $('<option></option>').html("--Wybierz-Wersję--"));
                $.each(models, function (i, model) {
                    $("#VersionModelId").append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(model.VersionModelId).html(model.VersionModelName));
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

**Problem**

*TestCase #1*: When page is loaded and I click submit button then validation messages are not displayed.

*TestCase #2*: When page is loaded and I select option "--Wybierz-Markę--" then the validation messages is not displayed (I suspect to be).

*TestCase #3*: When page is loaded and I select first option and next option "--Wybierz-Markę--" then the validation messages is not displayed (I suspect to be).

---

### Problem source:

I figure out that this peace of script brokes this functionality (when I comment this my code works well):

```js
$('#SearchCarsOffers').click(function () {

  var form = $("#SearchCarsOffersForm");
  var url = form.attr("action");
  var formData = form.serialize();
  $.post(url, formData, function (data) {
    areaChart.setData(data);
    //CreateMorrisArea(data);
  });
  return false;
});
```

**Please explain me where exactly is the problem and how can I fix it?**

---

Comment: did you check for class containing "error" when you it in the browser ? It can be css issue.

Comment: You mean html source generated by Razor: <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Model must be a number." data-val-range="The field Model must be between 1 and 2147483647." data-val-range-max="2147483647" data-val-range-min="1" data-val-required="Proszę wybrać model" id="SelectedModelId" name="SelectedModelId"><option value="">--Wybierz-Model--</option>
</select>

Comment: Ok, I have found where the problem is (described at the bottom). But still I don't know why this is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: (1) Your layout includes duplicated scripts (remove the 1st two) (2) `$('<option></option>').html("--Wybierz-Wersję--"));` does not add an option with a `null` value - its needs to be ``$('<option></option>').val('').html("--Wybierz-Wersję--"));`

Comment: (3). `if (form.Valid()) { $.post(....) { ... }); }`

Comment: Thank you Stephen for your tips. Options (2) and (3) are solutions. But I was not able to use this method "Valid()" in my JavaScript code. I tried to debug it and this method is "undefinied" (https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid).    I solved it in more conventional way: if ($("#SelectedBrandId").val() != "" && $("#SelectedModelId").val() != "")

Comment: Someone knows why this form.Valid() peace of code doesn't works? When I debug it an exception is thrown. And Chrome debuger see this method as "undefinied"...